# Java Radio Buttons within Radio Buttons

Tags: java, swing, radio-button, listener

I have learnt to create a menu with radio buttons using java, but I want to know how to make radio buttons WITHIN radio buttons. The real problem is that I have finally created the radio buttons 'within' a radio button by displaying a new menu with a new group of buttons, but whenever I click on these new radio buttons, nothing happens. It is as if the buttons are not being listened to. Here is my code (example, but still the same idea):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class TestRadioButtons extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    private String test = "Test Button 1";
    private String random = "RANDOM";

    private String test2 = "Button to Click";
    private String random2 = "RANDOM MK. 2"; 

    private static boolean menu = false;
    public TestRadioButtons()
    {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        //creates first set of radio buttons
        JRadioButton testButton = new JRadioButton(test);
        testButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_T);
        testButton.setActionCommand(test);

        JRadioButton randomButton = new JRadioButton(random);
        randomButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_R);
        randomButton.setActionCommand(random);

        //groups the first set of buttons
        ButtonGroup group1 = new ButtonGroup();
        group1.add(testButton);
        group1.add(randomButton);

        //register listener for first radio buttons
        testButton.addActionListener(this);
        randomButton.addActionListener(this);

        //put first radio buttons into a column in a panel
        JPanel radioPanel1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        radioPanel1.add(testButton);
        radioPanel1.add(randomButton);

        //set first menu border
        add(radioPanel1, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20,20,20,250));

        //I also have it so that if the a boolean value equals true, the following menu appears:
        if (menu == true)
        {
            JRadioButton test2Button = new JRadioButton(test2);
            test2Button.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
            test2Button.setActionCommand(test2);

            JRadioButton random2Button = new JRadioButton(random2);
            random2Button.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_B);
            random2Button.setActionCommand(random2);

            ButtonGroup group2 = new ButtonGroup();
            group2.add(test2Button);
            group2.add(random2Button);

            test2Button.addActionListener(this);
            random2Button.addActionListener(this);

            JPanel radioPanel2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
            radioPanel2.add(test2Button);
            radioPanel2.add(random2Button);

            add(radioPanel2, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20,20,20,250));
        }
    }

    public static void menu2()
    {
        JFrame innerMenu = new JFrame();
        innerMenu.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JComponent innerComponent = new TestRadioButtons();
        innerComponent.setOpaque(true);
        innerMenu.setContentPane(innerComponent);

        innerMenu.pack();
        innerMenu.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (test.equals(e.getActionCommand()))
        {
            menu = true;
            menu2();
            if (test2.equals(e.getActionCommand()))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This is just a TEST!");
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Radio Button Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JComponent component = new TestRadioButtons();
        component.setOpaque(true);
        frame.setContentPane(component);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If anyone is able to help me (as well as fix up my code in the part where I create the new menu), I would be grateful.

Comment: I haven't understood your request. Can you please explain it better?
I've executed your code and what happens is that when I click on the first radio button ('test button') another panel appears with another group of radio button. 
So what's the problem with that?

Comment: Alessandro Suglia: after I click the first radio button, it brings up the 2nd menu, yes. But, if you try click the 'Click Me' or whatever it says button, nothing happens, even though it should execute the message dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a `}` problem

Change your `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` like this

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

        if (test.equals(e.getActionCommand()))
        {
            menu = true;
            menu2();
        }
            if (test2.equals(e.getActionCommand()))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This is just a TEST!");
            }

    }
```